# Por que da este resultado? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy tomando el tutorial de python en w3 y en la seccion de lambda me dan este codigo

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

que da como resultado 22, eso lo entiendo, lo que no entiendo es por que la variable "a" obtiene el parametro de 11, es decir entiendo que "n" sea 2 porque se define en la tercera línea, pero cuando entra el 11? o mejor dicho, por que el 11 de la ultima línea termina por ser "a" dentro de lambda...

se que es una pregunta mas de entender la sintaxis que un error como tal, pero me gustaría entender eso antes de seguir

Comment: Ahí tienes una función que retorna una función, al hacer `mydoubler = myfunc(2)`  estas pasando el `2` como parámetro (que sería la variable `n`) y te retorna una función, eso quiere decir que `mydoubler` es una función que recibe un parámetro `a` y que al hacer `print(mydoubler(11))` le pasas `11`, la función se ejecuta y te retorna 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una operación de 2 pasos. Primero se pasa el 2 y se retorna una función anónima (lambda) preparada para recibir otro parámetro. Luego se le envía el 11 y la función anónima (que tiene un `return` implícito) devuelve la operación evaluada.

```
>>> def myfunc(n):
...     return lambda a : a * n
...
>>> mydoubler = myfunc(2)
>>> mydoubler
<function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at ...> # <-- devuelve una función
>>> print(mydoubler(11))
22
>>> myfunc(3)(20)
60
```

La misma función escrita de forma básica, sin lambda:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def lambda_(a):
        return a * n
    return lambda_
```

Sugiero leas algo de [funciones anidadas](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+funciones+anidadas), que es una característica muy útil del lenguaje y es el preámbulo para los [decoradores](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+decoradores).

Comment: Buena respuesta! Sin embargo, te aclaro que poner _ al principio es, por convención, para cosas internas (no me refiero de Python). Quizá quisiste decir lambda_

Comment: Si @DanteS. lo pensé, pero quería ilustrar al OP la función sin borrar el nombre de lambda. Como es mejor práctica, ya lo edité para dejarlo al final.

Comment: Asi que es una funcion anidada, tiene sentido, no lo veia asi porque no estaba tomando en cuenta que lambda es una funcion (a pesar de que lo sabia) y que ella estaba siendo utilizada como retorno para luego asignar "a" como parametro, gracias de verdad! :D